# How to get the attribute value of a XML node using XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

This is my script, but it only prints spaces in the console. Can someone explain how I can get the attribute values from a XML file using xPath?

```
    XPathNavigator nav;
    XPathDocument docNav;
    XPathNodeIterator NodeIter;
    XmlNamespaceManager ns;

    Int32 elementCount;

    String windowName;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        docNav = new XPathDocument("C:/BlueEyeMacro/DaMaGeX/Applications/WindowBuilder/GUI.xml");
        nav = docNav.CreateNavigator();
        ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(nav.NameTable); 
        elementCount = nav.Select("/GUI/window").Count;
        Console.WriteLine(elementCount);
        for (int i = 1; i <= elementCount; i++)
        {
            NodeIter = nav.Select("/GUI/window[@ID="+i+"]");
            windowName = NodeIter.Current.GetAttribute("name", ns.DefaultNamespace);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", windowName);
        }
    }
}
```

**XML File**
`<GUI>`
`<window ID="1" name="mainWindow" parent="0" type="0" text="My first window" options="Option 1;" actions="action 1;" exit="exit;" />`
`<window ID="2" name="secondWindow" parent="0" type="0" text="My second window" options="Option 1;" actions="action 1;" exit="exit;" />`
`<window ID="3" name="thirdWindow" parent="0" type="0" text="My third window" options="Option 1;" actions="action 1;" exit="exit;" />`
`</GUI>`

Comment: You code looks strange as it likely uses console output in WinForm project, but otherwise Select statements are reasonable. Please describe what problem you have.

Comment: DaMaGeX: You may be interested in a shorter/simpler solution than the currently-accepted one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, you have to call NodeIter.MoveNext() first like in this code:

```
XPathNodeIterator nodesText = nodesNavigator.SelectDescendants(XPathNodeType.Text, false);

while (nodesText.MoveNext())
{
    Console.Write(nodesText.Current.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(nodesText.Current.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can directly obtain the string value of the attribute:**

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= elementCount; i++) 
    { 
     // This obtains the value of the @name attribute directly
     string val = 
               nav.Evaluate("string(/GUI/window[@ID='"+i+"']/@name)") as string;                
     Console.WriteLine(val); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify your code to do this:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= elementCount; i++) 
    { 
        var NodeIter = nav.SelectSingleNode("/GUI/window[@ID='"+i+"']/@name"); //This selects the @name attribute directly
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", NodeIter.Value); 
    }
```

Given you are identifying a node by a unique id, SelectSingleNode is a better fit for what you are trying to do.